# Android Studio Buscar dispositivos gps

Tags: android-studio, gps

estoy desarrollando una aplicación que muestra en el mapa distintos tipos de información, como puntos de paraderos de locomoción y lineas (polyline) del recorrido de estos mismos y tambien debo crear una funcionalidad que me permita saber en que posicion del mapa se encuentra algun dispositivo gps (que en mi caso lo quiero emular con un celular inteligente), ¿como deberia hacerlo?, he buscado en internet, pero aun no estoy seguro de como deberia hacerse. Si alguien tiene conocimiento sobre esto, me puede hechar una mano por favor.

PD: Toda la información la voy a buscar a una base de datos con la que dispongo.
PD2: La ubicación del dispositivo que consulto deberia actualizarse cada cierto tiempo para saber por donde va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo Solucioné creando otra aplicación (llamemosla app 1), la cual sube a mi base datos su posición, y en el cliente que tengo (donde veo su ubicacion en el mapa, app 2) rescato los datos de su posición desde la misma base de datos.
El tema de la actualización de la posición lo soluciono creando un bucle en la app 1, y en la app 2 debería crear un bucle similar (aun no lo he hecho).